# If $k$ is an integer, and $\sqrt k$ is rational, show that $\sqrt k$ is an integer.

Tags: elementary-number-theory

I know this is a special case of a result that works in both directions for the nth root. But I'm trying to find a simple proof of this result.

Assume $gcd(p,q)=1$ and
$\sqrt k=\frac{p}{q}$, so $k = \frac{pp}{qq}$ and  $qqk=pp$ ---> Then some fundamental theorem of arithmetic magic comes next or something.

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Most all of the well-known proofs already appear here - see the linked answers (and the "Linked" questions there.

Comment: If $\gcd(p,q)=1$ then they don't have any nontrivial factors in common.  What does $k =\frac {p^2}{q^2}$ say about any factors $p$ and $q$ may have in common?